# AFNetworking - response null with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager when loging to app on second use - why ? how to clear all data?

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 and I have problem with my app.
The problem is that I can't login to server after logout in my app.
The path is:

```
1. user login to sprin security using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager
2. using app
3. click on logout - that do nothing only show loginviewcontroller
4. try to login again - and then any request to serwer give null response (status code 0)
```

Even restart my app is not enough. I need to reset my iPhone simulator and then everything works ok.
Why all network from app to server is broken ? I have no idea :/
Second question:
How to clear any data creaed by:
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
I mean: cache, session, anything maybe that is problem :/ ?

Comment: i'm facing same issues.Did you fix it? if means Can you please explain me how to resolve